# Is interest expense a cash flow transaction?

Tags: cash-flow

I keep my personal finances on ledger (http://www.ledger-cli.org/) and I am working to create a cash flow report. For this report, I'm listing all the income and expenses of the month and all the payments I make to debt. I keep track of interest charges as an expense, so it's showing on this report but I wonder if it should. Should any charge on the credit cards be on the cash flow report for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "Interest Expense" is an "Operating cash outflow".

If it is booked properly on the income statement, it should easily be shown on the cash flow statement by the [direct method](http://www.investopedia.com/exam-guide/cfa-level-1/financial-statements/cash-flow-direct.asp).

By the [indirect method](http://www.investopedia.com/exam-guide/cfa-level-1/financial-statements/cash-flow-indirect.asp), it will already be shown as operating cash flow by "Net income".